# When does Amazon Aurora DB start reading from replicas instead of the primary instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

My assumptions when asking this question are that Aurora will only write to the primary instance, and can read from either the primary or a replica instance. I guess based on that, as well as some observation of CloudWatch, I also assume that reading will first happen on the primary instance, and will only be moved over to a replica when some threshold on the primary instance is crossed.

If that is true (and please correct me if that isn't), what has to happen for read requests to be directed to a replica instead of the primary instance? So far, I've gotten my CPU Utilization on the primary instance up to 45%, but I haven't been able to see a significant enough change on the replica metrics (particularly the Queries metric) to think that read traffic was being redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are aware of some feature of Aurora that I am not, the type of load balancing you are describing does not exist with Aurora. You have to explicitly send read-only queries to the [Aurora reader endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-reader-endpoint-for-amazon-aurora-load-balancing-higher-availability/) for those to be distributed across your read replicas. If you just send queries to the primary endpoint they will always go to the primary instance.

Comment: Hmm--do you think that still applies even though I'm sending queries to the cluster endpoint, not the primary endpoint explicitly?

Comment: I'm back after some scrambled reading--so, the cluster endpoint always points to the current primary instance, and the reader endpoint will go to the read replicas and balance calls across them, and If I'm pummeling my primary instance (through the cluster endpoint), it won't redirect calls to the replicas but will instead take the beating until it falls over, in which case a new primary will be designated from the replica pool. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Now AWS has provided the custom endpoint creation for reader instances.So that can be used for load balancing between the reader instances.